# In a HTML email signature is there way to conditionally hide content?

Tags: exchange-2013, html-mail

[I've asked this on StackOverflow and was advised to put it on here.]

I have created a HTML email signature, in Exchange Admin Center, that uses variables to get data from active directory.  But, if any of these variables are empty the signature displays a blank space.

Is there any way - preferably without javascript (if possible) - to say if the variable is empty/null then don't display that line of content.

For example, if the email field is empty the signature will display 'E: [blank space]'. I'd rather it not display the Email line. The images are probably more helpful.

Here is the code [snippet] I'm using in the signature that I want to put conditions on...

```
<div class="all-info" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;padding-top: 15px">
   <h3 style="margin: 0px; color: #DB0E15">%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%</h3>
   <h4 style="margin: 0px; padding: 3px 0px 6px 0px;">%%title%%</h4>
   <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><span style="color: #DB0E15">E : </span>%%email%%</h5>
   <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 3px;"><span style="color: #DB0E15">T : </span>%%PhoneNumber%%</h5>
</div>
```

Note: It needs to work in Outlook as well as other clients/browsers.

Below are images to try and explain my problem better.

[image: Signature when email not blank]

Notice in this image, the line with email content is displayed with a blank email address.  Which is when I don't want the line to appear.

[image: Signature with blank email - don't want this line appearing]

Here is the HTML I am using...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table td { border-collapse: collapse; }
        .msoBord { mso-table-lspace:-1pt; mso-table-rspace:-1pt; border-right-color: #DB0E15; border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: medium;}
        .msoFix { mso-table-lspace:-1pt; mso-table-rspace:-1pt;}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: white;" bgcolor="white">
    <font face="Arial">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left">
              <div style="max-width:700px !important;">
                <table class="msoBord" width="120" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="white" >
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="padding: 0px;">
                    <a href="https://[our.web.address]/"><img src="[link to image]" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="msoFix" width="380" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="white">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="padding: 5px;">
                    <div class="all-info" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;padding-top: 15px">
                        <h3 style="margin: 0px; color: #DB0E15">%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%</h3>
                        <h4 style="margin: 0px; padding: 3px 0px 6px 0px;">%%title%%</h4>
                        <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><span style="color: #DB0E15">E : </span>%%email%%</h5>
                        <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 3px;"><span style="color: #DB0E15">T : </span>%%PhoneNumber%%</h5>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </font>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you use a script to auto-generate the signature file? If so you could put some logic in there to decide whether to put the line in or not maybe?

Comment: It's not a file.  It's just HTML code put into Exchange.

Comment: How is it put in? via a script? textbox? is this setting a default sig?

Comment: The latter. Default sig.

Comment: Javascript must be executed on the client side, but JS is not executed for HTML emails  — that'd be rather complex, and a huge security issue. The only way to deal with it is to not generate it in the first place. Possibly third-party tools like https://www.codetwo.com/exchange-rules-family/ can do that.

Comment: From [*what I can see*](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/email-signatures-on-exchange-server-2019/) this is a known issue with setting signatures in the disclaimer field in exchange (I'm guessing this is what you're doing), and can be fixed only with [3rd party tools](https://www.exclaimer.co.uk/email-signature-handbook/10070-exchange-2013-2016-2019-signature) like the two linked here. Alternatively you could use [group policy to generate a signature on logon](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2117731-configure-outlook-signature-through-group-policy) instead.